# HTML table with special layout

Tags: html, css, tablelayout

How can I make a table in css/html like this:

[image: http://i42.tinypic.com/15zp306.png]

I want to use only div, not `<table>` tags.

Code, yet:

```
<style>
.tab_in {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px dotted red;
    padding: 4px 6px;
}
</style>

<div style="text-align:center;">

<div class="tab_in">
<div>a</div>
<div>b</div>
</div>

<div class="tab_in" style="vertical-align:middle;">c</div>
<div class="tab_in" style="vertical-align:middle;">d</div>
<div class="tab_in" style="vertical-align:middle;">e</div>

</div>
```

Comment: What's the content of this "table" going to be?

Comment: that's... not super-informative. I should re-phrase my question: what is the layout intended to do?

Comment: I am sorry, i don't exactly understand... "a" will be text, "b" an image and everything else text. I want all cells but a and b to have equal dimensions. The big cell should have equal deimensions to cells c, d, e and f combined.

Comment: Is what I am trying to do impossible that way?

Comment: Okay. So a and b represent the two bits of content (text and image) on one cell? And the other cells (c - k) should all have the same width and height?

Comment: Is the idea to allow automatic reflow of the third column to be under the second column on smaller screen sizes? Intent is relevant to this... if your columns went (col1) a, b, (col2) c, e, g, i, (col3) d, f, h, j, that would be easier to accomplish, in some ways, but might not fit what you are trying to aim for. Do the items in the 2nd and 3rd columns /have/ to appear in that order?

Comment: Is the idea to allow automatic reflow of the third column to be under the second column on smaller screen sizes? <-- No, i don't want this. Thanks for asking.

Comment: Do the items in the 2nd and 3rd columns /have/ to appear in that order? <-- Yes sadly...

Comment: I can't think of any way to do it with the markup as given, then. You'd essentially have to have three column divs, then inside each column div have the individual cells in the order you wanted. element flow only works left to right (or rtl for some languages, iirc)... you can't flow something from the bottom of a column to the top of another using CSS, as far as I know.

Comment: Should the other cells (c - k) be as tall as required to contain the tallest bit of content in any of them?

Comment: Aha, thank you for the help! I will try to think an other way... If, say items a and b were one single item, will it be possible?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: i will store text on those cells, so i don't need them any tall.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand exactly waht you mean, i edited the code and removed everything not needed.

Comment: @Zen8000k: you say cells c - k should all be the same height. But what should that height be? If cells c - i have, say, 100 characters of text in them, and cell k has 100,000 characters, should all of the cells become as tall as cell k, or should cell k's text overflow?

Comment: Yes, all the cells should have the same height. I don't want anything to overflow.

Comment: Do the sum of the heights of the cells in the 2nd and 3rd cols have to equal the sum of the heights of the cells in the first column?

Comment: @Zen8000k: I don't think that's even possible with table tags.

Comment: @mori57: yes, exactly.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: can this be done with <table> tags or any other way?

Comment: Here's a `<table>` example showing how equal height for cells c - k, where the cells are all automatically tall enough to contain their content, doesn't happen: http://jsfiddle.net/DwdBn/

Comment: It's the closest solution to the problem, but some unexpected things happen, e.g. if table cell "a" is 200 characters, the text dissapears.

Comment: @Zen8000k: to figure out whether "it" can be done, we need a complete definition of what "it" is.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: that's even closer, only one issue: the table **cells** of all tables should be the same...

Comment: @Zen8000k: 1. You mean the width of all *cells* should be the same? 2. The width of all the cells *is* the same.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DwdBn/1/

Comment: @Zen8000k: you can fix the width of the cells, e.g. `td {width: 100px;}`, or `<td width="100">`.

Comment: Here the 2nd column items should have the same width as items on column 3. Also, the height should be the same on all cells. The sum is the same. But on the small cells, each cell should have the same height with every other.

Comment: Great job! Thats exactly what i need! One last thing: can this be done without <table>?

Comment: You can write the code on awnsers, so i can select yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use fluid grid system which uses percents instead of pixels for column widths. and handle the external width of it using a external container.

You can do something like:

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cgirish/Rmq3q/)**

**HTML**:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="row-fluid show-grid">
        <div class="span4">
            <div class="rowspan2">
                <span class="valign-helper"></span>
                a
            </div>
            <div class="rowspan2">
                <span class="valign-helper"></span>
                b
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            <div>c</div>
            <div>d</div>
            <div>e</div>
            <div>f</div>
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            <div>g</div>
            <div>h</div>
            <div>i</div>
            <div>j</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: to vertically align text you can also do using "display: table-cell" css property to the class 'rowspan2'. and remove the tag with class "valign-helper"

**CSS**:

```
body {
    margin: 50px;
}

.box {
    width:500px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    background-color: #000;
}

.show-grid [class*="span"] div {
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.show-grid [class*="span"] .rowspan2 {
    height: 90px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.valign-helper {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of one way you might accomplish this:

http://jsfiddle.net/mori57/cDEGw/1/

html:

```
<table class="tab_out">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="0" class="col">
            <div class="tab_in">a</div>
            <div class="tab_in">b</div>
        </td>
        <td><div class="tab_in">c</div></td>
        <td><div class="tab_in">g</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="tab_in">d</div></td>
        <td><div class="tab_in">h</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="tab_in">e</div></td>
        <td><div class="tab_in">i</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="tab_in">f</div></td>
        <td><div class="tab_in">j</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.tab_out {
    width: 800px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align:center;
}
.tab_out td {
    border:1px dotted red;
    padding: 4px 6px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.tab_in {
    display: block;
    border: 1px dotted green;
}
```

Is this any closer to what you're looking for? I really don't see an efficient way to accomplish your layout without using a table, at this point. Mind you, the div inside each TD is optional, I just used it to show you where the element actually appears inside the table.

Comment: Great, only one issue: a and b cells should be in the vertcical center, as show on the image.

Comment: I don't think your code quite implements what the OP is looking for. A & B aren't separate cells, they're content in one cell, which should be as tall as the other 4 cells put together. In your code, none of the cells affect each others' height: see e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/DBryN/1/

Comment: @Zen8000k: I thought a and b were content in one cell, not separate cells?

Comment: Yes, I want them content on one cell. If thats not possible, I have to find a way to do it, even if not 100% what I want.

Comment: OK, now we're getting to the meat of the issue (and yeah, @PaulD.Waite, I was pretty sure I wasn't giving him exactly what he wanted, but I wanted to offer an option that wasn't the one below, to start with...) ... give me a minute.

Comment: Mind you, I didn't see the latest comment before I did the above. You could set the .tab_in class to force the same height across all the contents that are classed with it.

Comment: The cells d-j should not be positioned there.

Comment: Huh? The layout matches your image, except that you left out "j" and skipped to "k"? Well, either way, good luck... basically, it looks like you're going to need tables one way or another.